# php ajax insert shows blank response but no error

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I am simply inserting a demo data by ajax form to database. The ajax shows no error but shows blank response when i  use `console.log(response);`.

Php code-

```
<form role="form" id="signup_form">
                            
            <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="required">First Name</label>
                 <div class="input-with-icon">
                   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your First Name"
                     name="f_name" id="f_name" required>
                  <i class="ti-user"></i>
                      </div>
              </div>
         </div>
         </div>

           <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"
                class="btn btn-md full-width btn-theme-light-2 rounded">Sign Up</button>
                    </div>

 </form>
```

ajax code-

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var f_name = $('#f_name').val();
        console.log(f_name);  // <--- but this shows the typed data from the form



        $.ajax({
            url: "homes/php/user-signup.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {

                "f_name": f_name

            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#signup_form')[0].reset();
                $('#signup').modal('hide');
                console.log(response); // <--- this shows blank response



            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(response);


            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

mysql --

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conf.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $f_name=$_POST['f_name'];

              $query = "INSERT INTO `user_info`(`first_name`) VALUES (':f_name')";

            $stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':f_name',$f_name);
            $stmt->execute();

  
 
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Echoing script tags and js code back to Ajax makes no sense. Just echo the text. The JavaScript on the browser can alert it, if it chooses to do so. The PHP should be neutral about how the message is presented.

Comment: @ADyson i removed the mysql files echo but still the problem lies in ajax

Comment: I didn't say to remove the echo...read it more carefully. Clearly if you remove the echo, you won't get a response in _any_ circumstances. I said to only echo the text you want displayed, rather than echoing a javascript code block.

Comment: Also if the query fails for any reason then (assuming you don't have PDO error reporting enabled) then it won't echo anything at all (because you didn't write any code which would do that). Or if the POST variables are not set correctly, it won't echo anything. So there are lots of possible reasons for an empty response. I assume you didn't try to debug it all before asking, then?

Comment: As the answer below points out, you're trying to detect a variable named "submit" in the $_POST variables, but it's very clear from the code here: `data: { "f_name": f_name }` that the only variable you're sending is one whose name is "f_name". So that would lead to the situation where you get an empty response because the POST variables aren't detected correctly. Change it to `if(isset($_POST['f_name']))` as advised. If it _still_ doesn't work after that, then you clearly have another problem as well - maybe the query fails, for example.

Comment: (BTW you could verify my points there with some simple debugging - checking outgoing and incoming data in the request using the browser's Network tool, and adding some echo's at other points in the PHP to see what path the code is taking. Learn to debug properly, it will save you a lifetime of headaches.)

Comment: i undestand your point. i tried debugging  with try catch block with PDOException still no error on mysql side

Comment: i had many variables name, email , pass username but for simplicity , i tried with only 1 variable .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're echoing a script block in the response, which makes no sense in an AJAX context.

Also you're *not* echoing any content in anything except the pure success case, and you're checking for the wrong variable in $_POST - your AJAX code only sends "f_name" to the server, nothing else.

You also have a typo in your SQL query - `:f_name` should not in in quote marks within the SQL string.

This should give you more feedback:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conf.php';

if(isset($_POST['f_name']))
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO `user_info`(`first_name`) VALUES (:f_name)";
    $stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':f_name', $_POST['f_name']);
            
    if($stmt->execute())
    {   
       echo "Signup Successful";
    }
    else 
    {
      echo "Error - query did not execute correctly. See error logs for details";
      //N.B. You should put some code here to log the real error to a file
    }
}
else
{
  echo "Missing parameters, please try again";
}
?>
```

If it *still* doesn't output anything after that, do some more debugging - check your browser's Console and Network tools to see if the request is even succeeding.

Comment: i tried your code and it says signup successfull but in db it displaying ":f_name" not the value typed.. i also put the screenshot in the question

Comment: Spotted a typo carried over from your original code: `VALUES (':f_name')` should be `VALUES (:f_name)`. Study examples of prepared statements more carefully! I've corrected it above. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php for examples.

Comment: now it works . But ,to insert many variables , should i be still using  if(isset($_POST['f_name']))  ??

Comment: Well, do some thinking! Ask yourself what that code does, and then you can make a decision. That code checks whether f_name is present. If that's your only _required_ field, then it will be fine to continue just with that. But if you have other required fields then you'll need to check for the existence of those as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change this `$_POST['submit']` to `$_POST['f_name']`. It will work. you didn't post `submit` in ajax request.

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'conf.php';

    if(isset($_POST['f_name'])){
            $f_name=$_POST['f_name'];

              $query = "INSERT INTO `user_info`(`first_name`) VALUES (:f_name)";

            $stmt = $dbcon->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bindParam(':f_name',$f_name);
            

            if($stmt->execute()){   
                echo "Signup Successfull";
            }else{
               echo "Insert failed. DB error";
            }
 
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: No, i tried that with f_name still doesnot work and btw why do i need to put $_POST['f_name'] ? because the button has id="submit" name="submit" . can you elaborate plz?

Comment: submit will work on form submit. Form will not submit in ajax. you will pass the required fields only in ajax data.

Comment: @jerry, Try my updated code. it should works.

Comment: remove single quotes from here `:f_name` insert query. check my answer. @ADyson, thanks.